# On Netbeans 8.1, how do I create a new Java project with a different package name?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

Is it possible to do so in Netbeans, or do I just have to manually change the package name each time I create a new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a project **MyJavaProject** with the main class *not* in a **myjavaproject** package, to this:

- Click **New Project...**
- Choose a Project Type
- Change the Package

  - Demonstrated below as the selected text
- Click **Finish**

[image]

This allows for one to create a new project with a different package name without having to manually change it after the project is created. Also note that this is *NetBeans 8.0.2*.